# react-router v4 one page scroll

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4

Is it possible to build scroll to anchor link page using react-router v4? like the example here https://codepen.io/jooleearr/pen/gpooKj. None of RRv4 document showed how to build it except for SPA with component.

This is what I would write in HTML....

```
<nav>
 <a href="#section1"> Section 1 </a>
 <a href="#section2"> Section 2 </a>
 <a href="#section3"> Section 3 </a>
<nav>


<section id="#section1"> Section 1 </section>
<section id="#section2"> Section 2 </section>
<section id="#section3"> Section 3 </section>
```

How do I correct write one with React Router?

```
const AppRouter = () => (
    <BrowserRouter>
        <div>
            <Header />
            <Switch>
                <Route path="/" exact={true} />
                <Route path="/second" />
                <Route path="/third" />
            </Switch>
        </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
);

const Header = () => (
  <header>
      <NavLink 
            to="#section1" 
            activeClassName="is-active" 
            exact={true}> Section 1</NavLink>
      <NavLink 
            to="#section2" 
            activeClassName="is-active">Section 2</NavLink>
      <NavLink 
            to="#section3" 
            activeClassName="is-active">Section 3</NavLink>
  </header>
);
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: Just use an anchor element

Comment: Can you elaborate? Can you explain how or where to use anchor element?